# Google Sheets - Cell contains text

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, cell

I have a google sheet with cells that contain different words. I want the words to equal numbers if present in a different cell. Normally I can just use =if when there is just one word but can't for this. I've tried using =regexactmatch and =search but can't get it to work.

For example the cell might contain the following text:
"Uruguay, France, Brazil, Belgium"

I want Uruguay, France, Brazil to each = 3 in another cell but Belgium to = 0 in that same cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think does what you ask:

```
=substitute(substitute(substitute(substitute(A1,"Uruguay",3),"France",3),"Brazil",3),"Belgium",0)
```

but, possibly like user who VTC'd as Unclear, I doubt it is what you want.